# calculate mean by group with split and sapply

Tags: r

In R, I used sapply+split function to calculate mean of the dataset iris.

**"There is a famous dataset in R called "iris". It should already be loaded in R for you. If you type in ?iris you can see some documentation. Familiarize yourself with this dataset.
Now obtain the mean of the first 4 variables, by species, but using only one function call."**

This is what I have:

```
sapply(split(iris[1:4],iris$Species),mean)
```

I received the error of "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

I do not know where I got wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: The code runs perfectly. Did you redefine `iris` or the `mean` function?

Comment: How to do the same thins: `mapply(sapply, split(iris[-5], iris[5]),MoreArgs =list(mean))`

Comment: `by(iris[-5], iris[5], colMeans)`

Comment: `aggregate(.~Species, iris, mean)`

Comment: `aggregate(iris[1:4], list(iris$Species), FUN=mean) `

Comment: `tapply(unlist(iris[-5]), list(array(iris[,5], dim(iris[-5])), col(iris[-5])), mean)`

Answer (score 2):

As `split` returns a list of dataframes, you need to change `mean` by `colMeans`:

```
> sapply(split(iris[1:4],iris$Species),colMeans)
             setosa versicolor virginica
Sepal.Length  5.006      5.936     6.588
Sepal.Width   3.428      2.770     2.974
Petal.Length  1.462      4.260     5.552
Petal.Width   0.246      1.326     2.026
```